# Approach to controlling which layers display in a QgsComposerLegend

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, legend

I've tried 2 approaches to control what shows up in *print* legends. Neither of them work which is troubling because other than pruning the layerRootTree in advance of composer.addItem(legend), there seems to be no way to display a layer in print without also displaying its symbol and name (as an entry) in the print legend's output.

```
    # APPROACH 1 - QgsComposerLegend(c).model()
    composerLegend = QgsComposerLegend(c)
    names = []
    excludes = ['100m', '10m', 'w001001']
    layer_set = []
    for node in self.getTreeLayers():
        layer = node.layer()
        if not layer.name() in excludes:
            layer_set.append(layer.id())
            names.append(layer.name())
    r.setLayerSet(layer_set)
    iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
    composerLegend.model().setLayerSet(layer_set)

    # APPROACH 2 - QgsComposerLegend(c).modelV2()
    composerLegend = QgsComposerLegend(c)
    composerLegend.modelV2().setRootGroup(QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findGroup('Land Uses'))
    composerLegend.synchronizeWithModel()
    composerLegend.updateLegend()
    c.addItem(composerLegend)
```

In the second approach the subgroups don't render properly in the legend and in the first all the layers show up regardless of the constraint assumably provided by setLayerSet.